# Multiple url in ssh config file

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I want user different [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) IAM account for different url (git repository)

**My ssh config file (do dot work):**

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/metro
  User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5AAAA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/taxi
  User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5BBBB
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

before add second repository I used this but now the 2nd repository use an other [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) IAM:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5AAAA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**EDIT**

do work:

```
Host git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5AAAA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

do not work:

```
Host metro
  Hostname git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5AAAA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host taxi
  Hostname git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5BBBB
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple ssh profiles you need to name them as a "Host".

Your ~/.ssh/config will look something like this:

```
Host metro
   Hostname git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5AAAA
   IdentityFile "/Full/Path/To/Your/.ssh/id_rsa"

Host taxi
   Hostname git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   User APKAJCGAGGG3PGQ5BBBB
   IdentityFile "/Full/Path/To/Your/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Although the [AWS docs for setting up SSH to the CodeCommit repo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html) indicate that the wildcard for the region in the hostname is valid, this does not work for me when I have multiple ssh profiles (could be a local setting of mine preventing this). When using multiple profiles you may need to use an actual region as noted above.

Once your profile is setup, to ssh you're simply going to type `ssh` plus the "Host" alias that you set; in the example above it's going to be `ssh metro` or `ssh taxi` and you'll be connected.

Comment: How to `git clone ...` and `git push`?

Comment: You can find this in step 4 of the AWS doc I linked to in my answer, you're going to `git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/metro metro-repo`

Comment: Enter the passphrase for the key and make sure it has 400 permissions

Comment: git clone ssh://git-codecommit.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/taxi
Cloning into 'taxi'...
FATAL: failed to begin relaying via HTTP.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: What do the "paths" in the `Hostname` lines do? They're not mentioned in your AWS docs link, though they are also in the question's config. In my experiments, I'm getting errors like `ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost/home: Name or service not known`

Comment: `Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com` do work but not `Host taxi
  Hostname git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/taxi`

Comment: @sgrillon – I'm pretty sure you can't put slashes in a `Hostname`. SSH doesn't have "paths"

Comment: OK, is it possible to have multiple conf for same host?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to reflect that paths are not supports parts of host names...

Comment: @sgrillon – You can have multiple `Host` stanzas that each have the same `HostName` (such as @hephalump's _metro_ and _taxi_ in this answer) but I wouldn't otherwise know how to get ssh to differentiate between otherwise-identical `Host` names.

Comment: taxi and metro do not have the same IAM user (different account)

Comment: Look at answer... Same host, different user fields. You have to put the correct values; put the appropriate username for the User value and the appropriate path to your key.

Comment: You edit your answer but do not work again. sorry. Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.